# Calculating p-values and pnorm() in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

I am trying to calculate the p-values of observations by comparing them to the normal distribution in R using `pnorm()`.  I have constructed a random distribution as my background model on which I would like to test the significance of various tests.  I know for example, my background normal distribution has a mean of 1 and a standard deviation of 3.

Say I have one test that I would like to test the significance of `test1 <- 20`. To obtain the p-value of a specific observation with a value of 20, I can use `pnorm(20, mean=1, sd=3)`. But what if for the same test, I have 5 repeated observations (technical repeats of the same test) with the values:

```
test1.rep1 <- 20
test1.rep1 <- 25
test1.rep1 <- 15
test1.rep1 <- 25
test1.rep1 <- 15
```

These 5 numbers have a mean of 20 and a standard deviation of 5. I could simply combine all of the repeated observed by taking the mean and then comparing to the normal distribution, i.e., `pnorm(20, mean=1, sd=3)`. But in this case, I am leaving out information, namely the standard deviation of these 5 observations. Is there an alternative way to include both the mean and standard deviation of the 5 observations when calculating the p-value?

---

The alternative is to calculate 5 p-values for each of the 5 observations of `test1`.

```
pnorm(20, mean=1, sd=3)
pnorm(25, mean=1, sd=3)
pnorm(15, mean=1, sd=3)
pnorm(25, mean=1, sd=3)
pnorm(15, mean=1, sd=3)
```

But then I have to find a way to combine these p-values, to end with one final p-value to look for significance.  I ultimately want to know if `test1` is significant.

I've looked into the Fisher method and the Stouffers method, but now I am thinking it may be better to just combine the values up front, rather than combining p-values.

Comment: If you want to know if a sample comes from a given probability distribution, you can use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: ks.test( c(20,25,15,20,15), pnorm, mean=1, sd=3 )

Comment: I see - I had not thought about it along these lines...will give it a shot and then respond back.

Comment: Does this test make sense if I only have beetween 4 and 9 numbers in my sample that I will be comparing to the normal dist? thanks!

Comment: `test1.rep1 <- 20; test1.rep1 <- 25; test1.rep1 <- 15; test1.rep1 <- 20; test1.rep1 <- 15` "These 5 numbers have a mean of 20 and a sd of 5" 
I just don't see how the mean works out to be $20$ since $(20+25+15+20+15)/5 = 95/5 = 19$ and the standard deviation is not $5$ either regardless of whether the mean is taken as $20$ or $19$.

Comment: I think that's a typo.  If you look slightly lower down, he lists his numbers as {20, 25, 15, 25, 15}, these have mean=20 & SD=5, and are identical to the above except that in the upper version the 4th value is 20 instead of 25.

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a typo.  
Gung is correct.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but it seems that if, under the null, X={20, 25, 15, 25, 15} are five independent draws from Normal(1, 9), then mean(X) will be distributed Normal(1, 9/5) and the usual single tail area computation proceeds as usual.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Fisher's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) of combining p-values, but it wouldn't be the preferred approach.  What you want to do here is a [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), specifically the [one-sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) version.  In R the [function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/t.test.html) is `t.test()`.  Here is a quick [tutorial](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/singlesample.html) I found by Googling.  The way this works is that you are just checking to see if your sample came from a population with a given mean.  In your case you want to know what the probability of getting a sample *as extreme or more extreme* as yours if they were drawn from a population with a mean of 1.  It's true that you want to take into account that your sample has a SD of 5.  We estimate the standard error of the sampling distribution of the mean by dividing the SD by the square root of N.  So, in your case, that would be $2.2=5/\sqrt{5}$.

Now, I should say here that your question taken literally (i.e., as stated) is about a $z$-test, not a $t$-test.  That's because you stipulate that you know *both* the population mean and SD.  I think this is the way you asked the question for the sake of understanding the issues (i.e., you wanted a well-defined problem).  In practice, this just doesn't really happen.  However, if that exact situation is really what you care about, then you would calculate the standard error of the mean by dividing the *known* SD by the square root of the number of data in your sample.  That is $SE = 5/\sqrt 3$, and thus your $SE = 1.3$.  Your $z$-score is $14$, and $p < .001$.  Here is the R code for that:

```
2*( 1-pnorm( 20, mean=1, sd=(3/sqrt(5)) ) )
```